# html datalist show option without matching prefix

Tags: html, forms

I have a search box and a `datalist` to suggest autocomplete and spelling corrections but the spelling corrections are not shown because they don't match the prefix of the input. For example if a user inputs "polution" and  I want to suggest "pollution" the option does not appear in the `datalist`. 
The `datalist` is populated using JS after each key press.

```
<input id="query" list="suggest" onkeyup="auto_suggest()" type="text" />
<datalist id="suggest"></datalist>
```

JS:

```
function auto_suggest() {

    //do an AJAX call and get back json with options

    suggest_list_html=''
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        suggest_list_html+='<option value="'+json[i]+'">'
    };
    document.getElementById('suggest').innerHTML = suggest_list_html
}
```

How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you show the population with js too. Did you tried on other browsers or just in chrome ?

Comment: I added the JS but I don't think that's the key. I want to change the default datalist behavior . Tried only in chrome.

Comment: Try on another browser and see if it works because i think its a chrome problem. Let me know than.

Comment: It's the same in Firefox and it seem datalist does not work at all on Safari